# Stop Ubuntu from using original swap partition

Tags: boot, swap

When I installed Ubuntu 16.04 I put it on a 250 GB SSD and created a 4 GB swap partition.  Recently I have been doing some machine learning and I keep using up all of my 16 GB of memory.  I decided to add a 120 GB SSD I had laying around and use it as a dedicated swap drive.  I made the following changes in /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=85206e1d-5f22-431d-8d17-bdc001895a8c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E478-855C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=ea40886f-8938-4629-b03d-ef30d5ff28c2 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=c23607a3-093e-4e2a-a34a-4ba10b6b603d none            swap    sw              0       0
```

As you can see I commented out the first swap drive and added the second one which is my 120 GB SSD.  The issue I am having is now Ubuntu mounts both drives as swap.  I do not want it to use the original 4GB partition on the boot drive.   I can manually turn off the swap for the boot drive using the disks manager but I want a solution which occurs automatically at boot.

Answer (score 1):

Try using gparted.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Right click your swap partition and select `swapoff`.